# Unable to get phone number and its type through phonegap contact plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to fetch contacts in my android app that I am building with phonegap. I am using phonegap build. I have added plugin in my config.xml.
Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // specify contact search criteria
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts
        options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results
       // filter = ["displayName","phoneNumbers"];  // return contact.displayName field
        var fields       = ["name", "phoneNumbers"];
        // find contacts
        // navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
        navigator.contacts.find(onSuccess, onError, fields, options);
    }


    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onSuccess(contacts) {
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
                $("#report_main_content").append('<li>'+contacts[i].displayName+' '+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value+' '+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].type+'</li>');

        }
    };

    // onError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
    }
```

The problem is I am able to fetch display name only but not phone numbers and their type. I went through phonegap documentation but its useless. I must admit the phonegap documentation is very poor.
I tried to alert contacts[i].displayName, which gives correct value. But when I tried to alert contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value the code execution stops. So how can I fetch Mobile number and their types?

Comment: I am using phonegap build to create .apk file. Phonegap version - 3.5.0

Comment: instead of phonegap build try to build locally..

Comment: comment `$("#report_main_content").append('<li>'+contacts[i].displayName+' '+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value+' '+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].type+'</li>');` this line and try put console or alert..

Comment: I tried it but no success. Though I haven't tried to build locally.

Comment: It was a plugin issue from Phonegap side which has been fixed now. The code is working fine now.